# How do we run IEdriverserver 32 & 64 bit simultaneously (.net binding)?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

My goal is to run both IE 32 & 64 bit driver simultaneously.
Earlier i used only 32 bit IEdriver server , so i added the IEDriverserver as an embedded resource inside the executable. Now since i have two(both 32 & 64) IEdriverserver and since .net selenium bindings require the name to be standard(IEdriverserver).
Once way is to download the zip and place both drivers into two separate folder paths(but that would be my last option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using different paths is the correct way to go here. That's the way the executable was originally designed.

Also, you should be aware that embedding an executable as a resource and extracting it at runtime is begging to have your application flagged by anti malware products as suspicious. Libraries like .dlls are less likely to be so flagged, but .exes are often problematic.

Comment: Thanks Jim. We run tests in a controlled/pre-set environments.
Was wondering if we can include 32 & 64 bit drivers in two seprate folders inside the project/solutions and configure these folders as embedded resources...so that when extract ...the drivers would fall into its folders as configured in the project/solution.